# Does $a$ being a zero of $f(x)$ in the integral domain $D$ imply that $x-a$ is a factor of $f(x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $F$ is a field. Here's the factor theorem for $F[x]$.

$a$ is a zero of $f(x)$ in $F$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $x-a$ is a factor of $f(x)$ in $F[x]$

However, I wonder what's the case for integral domains. Suppose D is a integral domain, it is obvious that the $\Longleftarrow$ of the above still holds. How about $\Longrightarrow$? Here the division algorithm does not hold any more so I can't prove it. It is also hard for me to come up with a counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true for any commutative ring with unity, you do not need an integral domain. Let $f=\sum_{j=0}^n c_jx^j$.

$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\sum_{j=0}^n c_j \frac{x^j-a^j}{x-a}$$ is always a polynomial because $\frac{x^j-a^j}{x-a}$ is well known to be a polynomial (use the geometric series or do the polynomial division by hand or whatever).

Comment: Thank you! I imagine the $=$ here is not rigorous? It's just means that the denominator $x-a$ mutipllying the polynomial on the right equals $f(x)-f(a)$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$